# what happens each time build method is called? is a new state object is created ? if so then it should call initstate method each time?

Tags: flutter, dart

is a new state object is created ? if so then it should call initstate method  each time?

The flutter framework will call this initstate  method exactly once for each state object it creates.

Comment: The point of a `StatefulWidget` vs a `StatelessWidget` is that a `StatefulWidget` has state that is preserved across widget rebuilds.

Answer (score 0):

The `State` object is  created only the first time a specific `widget` is built.

Then, even if the `widget` rebuilds, the `State` instance is preserved.
As such, `initState` is executed only once even if a `widget` rebuilds every frames.

Answer (score 0):

setState method is in State class and it rebuilds the widget by calling build method for dirty children.
if any stateful widget of which parent becomes dirty or we can say for some reason calls setState at that time that children will get recreated and so is it's State Object.

check the documentation of the createState method when it's going to be recreated.

```dart
  /// The framework can call this method multiple times over the lifetime of
  /// a [StatefulWidget]. For example, if the widget is inserted into the tree
  /// in multiple locations, the framework will create a separate [State] object
  /// for each location. Similarly, if the widget is removed from the tree and
  /// later inserted into the tree again, the framework will call [createState]
  /// again to create a fresh [State] object, simplifying the lifecycle of
  /// [State] objects.
  @protected
  @factory
  State createState();
```

for clarification 2 simple use cases

1. A class extends stateful widget if we call setState from any method of _Astate only build method will get called no initState no createState.
2. If A class extends stateful widget and in build method _AState class having B class which extends Statefulwidget then for any setState method call in _AState the B class will get recreated and so is the _BState class.
3. if from A class we go to the B route then init state will get called this is a bug from flutter end which I guess still not resolved. [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11655)

So all an all setState will not create state again it just rebuilds the widget tree.